# Saying ameen after surah fatiha when reading alone behind imam

Tags: salat, surat-al-fatihah

When praying behind Imam. If it's loud prayer, we have to recite Surah fatiha after Imam recites Surah fatiha. But before that when Imam finishes his fatiha we have to say Ameen. **But after that when i finish my fatiha do i have to say Ameen again?**

Comment: You are implying that you re-read tge fatihah after the imam which is not even agreed upon matter. And doesn't sound right ar all because you won't be able to listen to the imam's recitation.

Comment: Well there is other opinion that you have to recite surah fatiha after Imam in loud prayers even if while the Imam is reciting other surah, or the prayer will be invalid https://islamqa.info/amp/en/answers/26746

Comment: Yes but first there's no backup of this being the most correct nor the most appropriate view. It is just a weird workaround in order to recite al-Fatihah in order to avoid the prayer being invalid. In fact all scholars agree that the prayer or act of the imam is sufficient in congregation.

Comment: @Medi1Saif Well there is a clear Hadith that can back it up. That can be found in sunan abu dawood 823

Comment: Could you share the reference? The hadith from the fatwa you are referring to is no backup for this practice.

Comment: Why? It's clearly states that the prophet said to recite Surah fatiha behind him. After he offered fajr prayer.

Comment: hadith number 823 in sunan Abu Dawud is a weak hadith, so rulings cannot be derived from it when there are no more corroborating evidences. the most correct opinion among the scholars is the recitation of imam is enough for the congregation.